# Django + elpaginaton + ajax, didnt work detailview class

Tags: python, ajax, django

Simply my DetailView wont open new pages with **enabled**

> {% load el_pagination_tags %}
>
> {% lazy_paginate base_publications %}

But, if i disable those tags everything works fine(except endless pagination ofc).

Here an example:

**views.py**

```
class IndexPublication(AjaxListView):   
      context_object_name = 'base_publications'
      template_name = 'Post/base.html'
      page_template='Post/base_list.html' 

      def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):         
          if self.request.method == 'GET':
             return Post_model.objects.order_by('-published_date')

  class PublicationDetail(DetailView):  
       model = Post_model
       template_name = 'Post/post_detail.html'
```

**Base_list.html**

```
{% load el_pagination_tags %}

{% lazy_paginate base_publications %}

<ul class="grid-container">
    {% for post in base_publications %}

    <li>
        <a class="navbar" href="{% url 'publications:detail_publication' pk=post.id %}">
        <h3 class="title">{{ post.preview_title|linebreaks }}</h3> 
        <p class="text">{{ post.preview_text|safe }}</p>
        </a>
        <img class='preview'src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ post.preview_photo }}'>
        {{ post.published_date }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Post_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'Post/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post">
        {{ object.main_title }}
        {{ object.main_textbox|safe }}
        {% if object.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                {{ object.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

With el_pagination ive got an error if i try to click on my url.

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /post/15/
Failed lookup for key [base_publications] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}, {'object': <Post_model: #БагажЗнаний КАК НЕ БОЯТЬСЯ ЛЕТАТЬ НА САМОЛЕТАХ>, 'post_model': <Post_model: #БагажЗнаний КАК НЕ БОЯТЬСЯ ЛЕТАТЬ НА САМОЛЕТАХ>, 'view': <Post.views.PublicationDetail object at 0x05146B50>}]
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.2:8080/post/15/
**Django Version:   2.1.3**
Exception Type: VariableDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Failed lookup for key [base_publications] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}, {'object': <Post_model: blabla, 'post_model': <Post_model: blbla>, 'view': <Post.views.PublicationDetail object at 0x05146B50>}]
Exception Location: C:\Users\poker king\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in _resolve_lookup, line 850
Python Executable:  C:\Users\poker king\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
**Python Version: 3.6.7**

**Error during template rendering**
In template C:\seniortravel\Post\templates\Post\base_list.html, error at line 3

Failed lookup for key [%s] in %r
1   {% load el_pagination_tags %}
2   
3   {% lazy_paginate base_publications %}
```

I`m kinda new for this. And give up on googling this problem.
Thx for your assistance.

Comment: Problem was in base.html - i use {% include %}, but after i change to {extends base.html} in base_list all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in base.html - i use {% include %}, but after i change to {extends base.html} in base_list all works fine.